# Aligatoring paint repair? Drywall

Tags: repainting

My 1920's house that was last updated in the 60s full gut job. Has aligatoring paint.

House spent 10+ yrs abandoned.

Wondering what the best coarse of action is requide for dealing with aligatoring paint on drywall only did this in my living room. None of the wood trim did this either. Prolly hasn't been painted since the drywall was put in the 60's.

Located where it goes to -40s -50s in the winter.

Gutting is not something I feel like doing it's a long drive to buy drywall as it's 12hrs one way.

Also I have a latex allergy opening a can gives me hay fever.

Comment: How about a few pictures.

Comment: Yes, pictures would go a long way toward explaining what "aligatoring paint" is.

Comment: If the house was completely abandoned for 10 years then you’re probably looking at removing all the drywall anyway.

Comment: Quite possible you would want to redo all the insulation to modern standards, unless you are sitting on a pot of gold to heat.  60s had 2x4 walls with hopefully R-12 and maybe R-20 in the ceiling, probably drafty also.

Comment: I have found on extensive remodels that were in bad shape the best first step is to bake the house for a week or longer.  make sure your moisture reading on the Sheetrock/ drywall is stable if not another week may be needed. Baking at 90 deg F with a couple fans pushing air around the first advantage is the pealing paint flakes off fairly easily and then a quick skim coat of mud makes the walls look like new. All for much less than other methods. Then prime and paint the building looks new.

Comment: It's heat was turned back on in 2018 just getting tired of looking at the Cracked paint. It's not peeling. The house is very dry. Only moisture issue it had was normal basement stuff and didn't take much to clear that up was really surprised how easly it cleaned up.  The exterior walls have vermiculite in them from the 20's and the  Buffalo board then the drywall ontop of that so it's not bad when it's-40. Found insulating the basement made huge difference. Attack has lots

Comment: You can still skim coat it to fill the cracks or sand it down and hit it with a texture spray that will usually hide the cracks in the paint.